# Automatic Play of Windows Media Player after Form Load

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have successfully incorporated a Windows Media Player into my form.  However, when the form loads, the Player does not "automatically" begin to play.  I must click the "play" button on the player or the button I made to do it.  My question is:  Must I put code into the form to make the player begin automatically when the page loads?

I tried incorporating the following code but it did not work.  lol.
Player.controls.play()

```
Private Sub AxWindowsMediaPlayer2_Enter(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles AxWindowsMediaPlayer2.Enter
    ' [Visual Basic]
    AxWindowsMediaPlayer2.currentPlaylist = _
  AxWindowsMediaPlayer2.mediaCollection.getByName("DSCN2226")
    Player.controls.play()
End Sub
```

I get no error messages as the Player does work - just not automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Place the code to start your player on the form and it will start automatically.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    AxWindowsMediaPlayer2.currentPlaylist = _
  AxWindowsMediaPlayer2.mediaCollection.getByName("DSCN2226")
    Player.controls.play()
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Josh.  Works perfectly.  I feel so silly as I know I should have tried that.  It just never entered my mind.  I guess I was too wrapped up up in thinking it was a "code" problem and not a "placement" problem.  Again, thank you for your timely response.

Comment: Yea. Different events have their function. You can also check the form_activated event. Accept the answer then.